# Confluent Platform connectors missing

Tags: apache-kafka, etl, confluent-platform

I have downloaded and run Confluent Platform 6.1.0. When I run the command to list available connectors I cannot see any JDBC or S3 connectors. All I can see is file connectors and replicator. What I need to enable S3 and Jdbc connectors.

Answer (score 1):

As of 6.x, the Confluent written connectors are no longer packaged with Confluent Platform, and you must use `confluent-hub` CLI to install or download them on your own